# Правильно ли обособлены вставные конструкции?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вставная-конструкция

Меня интересуют запятые, стоящие перед и после тире. Можете пожалуйста поделиться правилами насчёт пунктуации при вставных конструкциях.

"Один из визитёров ввалился в окно, чтобы занять удобную позицию рядом с барной стойкой(_) – этот человек уже не раз бывал в этом трактире, поэтому прекрасно знал, где и что находится(,) – но как только он показался Пайдею на глаза, его голову тотчас размозжила револьверная пуля".

"Рана была еле заметной и совсем не кровоточила, хотя рыцарские клинки(*) – неважно, будь то сабля или кинжал(*) – оставляли после себя куда более серьёзные следы".

И у меня нет примера, когда вставная конструкция обособляется запятыми с обеих сторон, вроде [...], – [вставная конструкция], – [...], так что буду признателен, если кто поделиться образцом.

Comment: Джин, Вы уж определитесь в терминологии: вводная конструкция (как в вопросе) или вставная (как в метках)? Это ведь совершенно разные вещи. Думаю, что все-таки вставная. P. S. Определяйтесь, правьте — вопрос мне видится интересным.

Comment: Хорошо. Впредь учту, что нужно верно формулировать вопрос, однако изменить его, как полагаю, уже не могу. Насколько мне известно, редактировать уже заданные вопросы вроде бы нельзя.

Comment: Свой собственный вопрос Вы можете изменить в любое время (с помощью "Править").

Answer (score 1):

1. *Один из визитёров ввалился в окно, чтобы занять удобную позицию рядом с барной стойкой,  **– этот человек уже не раз бывал в этом трактире, поэтому прекрасно знал, где и что находится,** – но как только он показался Пайдею на глаза, его голову тотчас размозжила револьверная пуля.*

Знаки "запятая и тире" здесь ставятся симметрично. Вставка всегда выделяется двумя тире, вопрос связан с постановкой запятых.

Вторая запятая не вызывает сомнения – это так называемая **"перенесенная"** запятая, **обозначающая структуру** предложения перед союзом НО.

Но и первую запятую нужно ставить, так как вставка имеет общий характер, относится ко всему предложению, а **не к его первой части.**

2. *Рана была еле заметной и совсем не кровоточила, хотя рыцарские клинки – **неважно, будь то сабля или кинжал** – оставляли после себя куда более серьёзные следы.*

Здесь ставятся только тире, так как на месте вставки не было никаких знаков.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125  (пункт 4)

Comment: *Но и первую запятую нужно ставить, так как вставка имеет общий характер, относится ко всему предложению, а не к его первой части* — где вы такое вычитали?

Comment: Вы не поверите, но это  интуиции, oleedd. Вы ведь примерно представляете, откуда «вычитываются»  интуитивные знания? Или пусть это будет СИММЕТРИЯ знаков (если в официальной версии).  При симметрии мы не относим  вставку ни к одной из частей в силу ее распространенности (так что можно считать, что   симметричный знак – это как бы аналог скобок).

Comment: Здесь вставка даёт информацию о том, как он мог знать про удобную позицию рядом с барной стойкой. Но решили закрыть придаточное, относя вставку к "один из визитёров". Теоретически это допустимо, только хуже.

Comment: oleedd, мы с вами никак не придем к единому пониманию того, что знаки препинания нужны для удобного чтения и быстрого понимания структуры предложения (а не только для соответствия правилам Розенталя, как многие думают). Симметричные знаки говорят  нашему читателю о том, что всю фразу нужно озвучить на втором плане речи, выделив ее общим пониженным тоном и одинаковыми паузами. И не важно, каково содержание этой фразы, все связи мы все равно не будем просчитывать.

Comment: Но если мы не поставили первую запятую, то вставку (обычно небольшого объема) нужно отнести к первой части предложения, чтобы подчеркнуть их тесную связь. А что нам здесь подчеркивать? Вставка   объемная,  первая часть также распространенная,  а вы должны в устной речи произнести все это с практически отсутствующей паузой. Это невозможно сделать, поэтому и не нужно делать! Сизифов труд или чей там еще? Другими словами, бесполезные упражнения, не имеющие смысла.

Comment: *А что нам здесь подчеркивать?* — ну это ж очевидно: *чтобы занять удобную позицию — этот человек уже не раз бывал в этом трактире, поэтому прекрасно знал, где [удобная позиция]*.

Comment: Распространенность первой части и вставной конструкции не позволяет прочитать 20 слов в одну фразу - это даже если вы что-то хотели там подчеркнуть. Технически, так сказать, невозможно (чтоб уж совсем понятно было).  Занимаетесь мелкими деталями там, где нужно показать масштабность события.

Comment: При вставке нет необходимости читать что-то в одну фразу. Вставка — это как комментарий, предложение внутри другого — и читается оно так же. И речи быть не может о прочтении в одну фразу. Что-то вы увлеклись.

Comment: Ладно, делаем вывод. Нет ничего важнее при составлении текста, чем оформить вставку запятыми. Только пусть оформители пораскинут мозгами, для чего ЧИТАТЕЛЮ  нужны их запятые. Может, тогда вы согласитесь со мной. Или себя спросите:  какой смысл в этих запятых?  Стандартом должно быть симметричное оформление, а одна запятая – это отклонение, частный случай, достаточно важный для понимания смысла.  В приведенном примере я такой необходимости не вижу. Кроме того, симметрия может быть авторским решением, Розенталь эту тему подробно не раскрывал (разумный был человек, лично я его понимаю).

Comment: Два тире — это как две скобки, запятая, если она нужна, ставится после второй скобки. То есть используется логика употребления скобок. На самом деле всё наоборот: симметрия — это отклонение от нормы. Может, тогда просто не было правил для вставки. В данном примере необходимость есть, вставка чётко относится к придаточному по смыслу: *хотел занять удобную позицию, так как часто там бывал и прекрасно знал, что где находится*.

Comment: Это у вас он искажённый (выдумываете всякое странное) ツ У меня он стандартный, как по правилам.

Comment: Ладно, забудем,  извините.  Пусть  ваше мнение будет стандартным и правильным.